# input type="file" - accept files without any extension

Tags: javascript, html

how do I accept files without any extension?
I need to accept **.json** and **no-extension** files
I tried

```
<input type="file" accept=".json, . "/>
```

and some variations of it with dot and empty space, but none of them work

Comment: Input of type file to accept files with no extension? Why?

Comment: @lonut i guess for evil purpose :D

Comment: @Ionut why not? Wolf, AFAIK you can use a  [media type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) instead of a file extension for the `accept` attribute. This should hopefully allow files without extension but still check their type. I don't know how that check is performed though - if it relies on the file extension... oh well. Give it a try.

Comment: @domdom — It's a browser implementation detail, but I'm not aware of any that don't use the file extension.

Comment: @Quentin good to know. And unfortunate in this case. I guess server-side checking it is then (that should be done in addition anyway).

Comment: @Abdoutelb there is nothing evil about files without a file extension. Quite the contrary, relying on the extension is the dangerous thing to do.

Comment: @domdom so I guess I'm out of luck. Files that I need to target are without extension and without type

Comment: @Quentin same as my previous comment

Comment: Yeah, just perform the required checks on the file server-side. You would need to do that anyway; the client-side "solution" with `accept` is more of a convenience to error out as easily as possible, but you can't rely on it: users could easily rename an `.exe` file to `.json` or simply remove the `accept` attribute from the `input` before using the form.

Comment: @domdom it's an Chrome extension. Loading files in it. I'm doing JS validation, but I wanted to filter it in prompt too

Comment: Google drive saves .jpg files and probable many other types without an extension, so reading them from the client side requires accepting files with no extension, and then performing a client side validation using something like this: https://github.com/spine001/client-side-validation-of-file-type

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in HTML file input yet.If you want it you can develop this feature either by serverside progamming or javascript validation. Accept all format files and Validate format and find desired formats and restrict  all other formats.

Comment: Suggestion: You might want to give OP some pointers on how to do either of these validations you mentioned. Also, check OP's newest comment.

Comment: I'm doing JS validation anyway... Is there any html `restrict method`, like accept all but .... Maybe that would filter out files without extension

Comment: nvm, I'll go with either instructing users to rename file or I'll accept all files